# PowerShell closes immediately

Tags: powershell

I am simply trying to open PowerShell and the application closes instantly. This happens when I try opening it as an Admin.

I tried input command 'powershell /' on command prompt in admin mode. it gives me an error:
The shell cannot be started. A failure occurred during initialization:
The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives' threw an exception.

I also tried to search for some solutions online but there is not that much helpful information.

Please provide any helpful suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388394/the-type-initializer-for-system-management-automation-runspaces-initialsessions) - if that's not the same issue, please provide version details (OS + PowerShell/WMF)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. OS is windows10 19H1. Powershell should be the latest version, but it fails to open, I can't check its version now.

Comment: Does it open if you run `powershell -noprofile`?

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Thanks for your reply. I just tried this out, it threw the same exception.

Comment: To me it sounds like at least one of the powershell assemblies is corrupt. You might want to try repairing Windows with DISM, see if that helps.

Comment: There's a long conversation with MS about this problem [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1638).